# MSSQL 2012 64bit JDBC connection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to connect to an SQL Server database 64bit using a JDBC connection to no avail. I used the standard drivers found online (sqljdbc42.jar and mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar) but they didn't seem to work. Is it possible that the drivers are 32bit and that messes up the connection. I'm able to create an ODBC connection through Windows (*both* 32 and 64 bit connections) and connect using JdbcOdbc driver but this one is deprecated on Java 8 and I can't use a previous version. What can possibly be the issue? The JDBC log simply says that it was not able to establish a connection and to check for Firewall issues and whatnot (which obviously do not exist since we're able to connect using ODBC).

Please note that I'm not the one who has configured the SQL Server instance but the DB Admins of our client so I am not aware of any specific configurations they might have done. It is a database used by a `File360` application they have if that helps.

Below is the code I use (which shouldn't be relevant because it used to work before the client migrated to the new Windows Server machine)

```
private void initUsingJDBC(Properties configurationProperties) {
    logger.debug("Creating datasource using driver: " + configurationProperties.getProperty("driverName"));
    DriverManagerDataSource frameworkDS = new DriverManagerDataSource(configurationProperties.getProperty("driverName"));

    frameworkDS.setUrl(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkDBUrl"));
    frameworkDS.setUsername(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkDBUser"));
    frameworkDS.setPassword(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkDBPass"));
    logger.info("Setting up framework datasource on url: " + frameworkDS.getUrl());

    frameworkJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(frameworkDS);

    DriverManagerDataSource dataDS = new DriverManagerDataSource(configurationProperties.getProperty("driverName"));

    dataDS.setUrl(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataDBUrl"));
    dataDS.setUsername(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataDBUser"));
    dataDS.setPassword(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataDBPass"));
    logger.info("Setting up data datasource on url: " + dataDS.getUrl());
    dataJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataDS);
  }
```

This fails to connect using the following configurations:

```
driverName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
frameworkDBUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://vm-micro-dbprod\\SQL2012;databaseName=File360_Framework
```

However, using ODBC it connects successfully:

```
private void initUsingODBC(Properties configurationProperties) {
    logger.debug("Creating odbc datasource " + configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkODBCUrl"));
    DriverManagerDataSource frameworkDS = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    frameworkDS.setDriverClassName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    frameworkDS.setUrl(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkODBCUrl"));
    frameworkDS.setUsername(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkDBUser"));
    frameworkDS.setPassword(configurationProperties.getProperty("frameworkDBPass"));
    logger.info("Setting up framework datasource on url: " + frameworkDS.getUrl());

    frameworkJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(frameworkDS);

    logger.debug("Creating odbc datasource " + configurationProperties.getProperty("dataODBCUrl"));
    DriverManagerDataSource dataDS = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataDS.setDriverClassName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    dataDS.setUrl(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataODBCUrl"));
    dataDS.setUsername(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataDBUser"));
    dataDS.setPassword(configurationProperties.getProperty("dataDBPass"));
    logger.info("Setting up data datasource on url: " + dataDS.getUrl());
    dataJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataDS);
  }
```

Where the ODBC connections have been defined using Windows 10's `ODBC Data Sources` (both 32bit and 64bit work).

Comment: Are you trying to use `integratedSecurity=true`? If so, then there *may* be a 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue surrounding `sqljdbc_auth.dll` on Windows clients.

Comment: Is that a Java parameter? If yes, then no I'm not using it. Note that I'm not the one who has configured SQL Server, it is the DB Admins of our client that have and I don't have any information on any specific configurations that they might have done at the moment.

Comment: Yes, `integratedSecurity=true` is a connection URL parameter. You haven't given us much to work with. Consider an [edit] to your question that shows the connection URL and the complete exception message.

Comment: Please show the code you use, and any relevant exception stack traces.

Comment: I added the code I use although you should know it is not really relevant since it used to work before the client migrated to a new Windows Server machine.